# HashMap Java как добавлять по значению?

Tags: java, search, java-hashmap, hashmap

Как можно добавить элемент в `map` по значению? Например, мне нужно написать `Имя Вася`. Программа посмотрит, если `Вася` есть, то выведет его `Номер` и `Имя`, а если `Васи` нет, то попросит добавить ему номер и сохранит в `map`. Я вроде как разобрался как добавлять по номеру, а вот как по имени не могу понять.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // командой LIST вывести весь список в алфавитном порядке с номерами
    // если пользователь пишет номер и он не найден, просит ввести имя, и запоминает номер и имя
    // если номер найден то выводит информацию (номер) (имя)
    // если вводишь имя то выводит информацию (номер)(имя)
    // если такого имени нет то просим ввести номер и запоминаем(имя)(номер)

    HashMap<Integer, String> numbers2Names = new HashMap<>();
    numbers2Names.put(100, "Vasya");
    numbers2Names.put(200, "Petya");
    numbers2Names.put(300, "Grisha");
    numbers2Names.put(400, "Misha");
    numbers2Names.put(500, "Pasha");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (;;) 
    {
        
        System.out.println("Plz write command ADD- add new person, LIST - show all persons");
        String command = scanner.nextLine();
        
        //вывод всего списка
        if (command.equals("LIST")) 
        {
            for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> item : numbers2Names.entrySet()) 
            {
                System.out.println("Number: " + item.getKey() + " Name: " + item.getValue());
            }
        }

        //добавление по номеру
        if (command.equals("ADD"))
        {
            String name = "";
            int number;
            System.out.println("Plz write number");
            Scanner numScan = new Scanner(System.in);     //считываем с консоли номер
            number = numScan.nextInt();     //сохраняем в переменную

            //проверяем есть ли уже такой номер, если нет то добавляем
            if (numbers2Names.containsKey(number)) 
            {
                // такой номер есть и выводим номер-имя
                System.out.println("this number exists");
                System.out.println("Number: " + number + " Name: " + numbers2Names.get(number));
            } 
            else 
            {                   
                System.out.println("This new Number, Plz write name this number");
                Scanner nameScan = new Scanner(System.in); //считываем с консоли имя
                name = nameScan.nextLine(); // сохраняем в переменную
                numbers2Names.put(number, name); //добавляем в hashmap номер и имя
                System.out.println("person save");                    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Может сделать ключ и значение String ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По заданию вижу, что нужно многое поменять:

- Чтение имени или номера для поиска (сейчас есть только поиск по номеру)
- Проверка существования как номера, так и имени в таблице (сейчас есть проверка только номера)
- Проверка номера или имени при добавлении новой записи (сейчас этого нет)

  ```
   mainLoop: for (; ; ) {

       System.out.println("Plz write command ADD- add new person, LIST - show all persons");
       String command = scanner.nextLine();

       //вывод всего списка
       if (command.equals("LIST")) {
           for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> item : numbers2Names.entrySet()) {
               System.out.println("Number: " + item.getKey() + " Name: " + item.getValue());
           }
       }

       //добавление по номеру
       if (command.equals("ADD")) {
           System.out.println("Plz write number or name");
           Scanner numScan = new Scanner(System.in);     //считываем с консоли номер
           String name = numScan.next();     //сохраняем в переменную
           Integer number = null;

           // пробуем понять, что это число
           try {
               number = Integer.parseInt(name);

               // есть номер существует в таблице, то выводим результат
               if (numbers2Names.containsKey(number)) {
                   // такой номер есть и выводим номер-имя
                   System.err.println("This number exists");
                   System.err.println("Number: " + number + " Name: " + numbers2Names.get(number));
                   continue ;
               }
           } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
               // если имя существует в таблице, то выводим результат
               if (numbers2Names.containsValue(name)) {
                   for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : numbers2Names.entrySet()) {
                       if(entry.getValue().equals(name)) {
                           System.err.println("This name exists");
                           System.err.println("Number: " + entry.getKey() + " Name: " + entry.getValue());

                           continue mainLoop;
                       }
                   }
               }
           }

           // если ни номера, ни имени не существует в таблице, то добавляем значение
           if(number != null) {
               System.out.println("This new Number, Plz write name this number");

               Scanner nameScan = new Scanner(System.in); //считываем с консоли имя
               name = nameScan.nextLine(); // сохраняем в переменную

               if (numbers2Names.containsValue(name)) {
                   System.err.println("Name already exists");
               }
               else {
                   numbers2Names.put(number, name); //добавляем в hashmap номер и имя
               }
           }
           else {
               System.out.println("This new Name, Plz write number this name");

               Scanner nameScan = new Scanner(System.in); //считываем с консоли число
               number = Integer.parseInt(nameScan.nextLine()); // сохраняем в переменную

               if (numbers2Names.containsKey(number)) {
                   System.err.println("Number already exists");
               }
               else {
                   numbers2Names.put(number, name); //добавляем в hashmap номер и имя
               }
           }
       }
   }
  ```

Comment: Спасибо.Я еще try catch не проходил, но ваш вариант работает,  есть идея сделать Map где ключ и значение будут String и проверять уже их.

Comment: @porosenok в данном примере try catch это небольшой трюк, конструкция используется не совсем по назначению)

Answer (score 1):

Поменяй местами номер с именем
`Map<String, Long>`

И потом `(if !map.containsKey(name){..}`

UPD

Для того чтобы значения в коллекции были как и ключи, уникальными, есть два способа. Насчет первого: вы можете использовать библиотеку guava и BiMap оттуда - она гарантирует не только уникальность ключей, но и значений, более того, ключ можно получить из нее по значению. Документация : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/guava/guava_bimap.htm

Второй вариант, это перед вставкой проверять, есть ли такое имя, в этом поможет метод `containsValue()` , и если содержит, то получить пару, например:

```
String targetName = "Ivan" ;
if(map.containsValue(targetName)) {
for(Map.Entry<Long, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
if(entry.getValue().equals(targetName){
//some logic 
}
} 
}
```

Можно так же заменить на стримы и optional:

```
map.stream()
.map(Map::entrySet)
.filter(entry - > entry.getValue().equals(targetName))
. orElseGet(() - > //insert) ;
```

Как то так. Не факт что без ошибок) в среде удобнее чем с телефона

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но тут нужно чтоб номера были уникальными, и если поменять местами, то как тогда искать по значению.Как искать по ключу я вроде разобрался, проблема именно в поиске элемента по значению. Лан, буду разбираться)Думаю сделать Map cо String ключ, String значение и так попробовать.

Comment: Дописала ответ.).)